# Generating Irrelevant Variables for a Kernel Regression

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Assume that my data generating process is $$y = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x_1)} + u,$$
where $u$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and small variance. I sample from this process by randomly sampling 100 iid $\mathcal U(-3,3)$ draws for $x_1$. Now I want to show that another variable $x_2$, with the same distribution as $x_1$ but independent of $x_1$, is irrelevant. Since $x_2$ is not included in the above described process, $x_2$ is also independent of $y$.

I essentially want to replicate Fig 1 and 2 from https://faculty.ucr.edu/~taelee/paper/2019%20AIE40B%20Chu%20Lee%20Ullah.pdf Regressing $y$ on $x_1$ yields Fig 1. But I don't understand how Fig 2 was produced. I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding what it means to include an irrelevant variable in a nonparametric context. How would I include an irrelevant variable in this setting?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "irrelevant"?  Is $x_2$ independent of either of $x_1$ or $y$?

Comment: $x_2$ is irrelevant of $x_1$ and $y$

Comment: It's useless to explain "irrelevant" using the word "irrelevant"!

Comment: sorry, I meant independent of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing at the paper, it seems values of $x_2$ are simply sampled i.i.d. from a uniform distribution $U(-3,3)$. As mentioned, $x_2$ is independent of both $x_1$ and $y$. Fig. 2 is just a scatterplot of $y$ vs. $x_2$, along with a kernel regression fit. This is the same as Fig. 1, but fitting $y$ as a function of $x_2$ instead of $x_1$.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I was suspecting it but not entirely sure since I could not reproduce the example and found to argument given in the paper not convincing (they argue about the bivariate function but show the 1d plots).